# ¿como hacer para serializar en Json solo un campo de un objeto que es un campo de otro objeto?

Tags: java, json, annotation

ES decir yo tengo una clase Alumno así:

```
public class Alumno extends Persona
{

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -5168392367836972065L;

 @ManyToOne
 private Profesor tutor;


 @ManyToOne
 private Curso curso;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alumno", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 private Set<Matricula> matriculas = new HashSet<>();
```

Luego tengo la clase Curso la cual tiene una propiedad llamada código, entonces, cuando yo a traves del restful, des de el cliente, recupere un alumno, no quiero el objeto Curso entero, solo quiero el código del curso, hay alguna anotación como del estilo @JsonIgnore, para solo enviar el código del curso?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que anotar la clase con algo así (si existe) se presta a generar un conflicto más adelante si otra consulta si requiere enviar el resto de los datos.

La solución que encontré a este tipo de problemas es usar DTOs (Data Transfer Objects). Se trata de Objetos sin funcionalidad que solo sirven para trasladar datos entre capas de la aplicación.

En tu caso concreto creas una clase AlumnoConsultaXxxDTO con la infomración a incluir en el Json.

Luego haces que el controlador rest busque el Alumno con todos sus datos, y llenas el DTO con los datos a devolver.

Y finalmente devuelves el DTO.

```
public class AlumnoConsultaXxxDTO{
    ... 
    public long curso; 
    ...
    // Sin setters ni getters, atributos publicos
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("alumnos")
public class AlumnoRestController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public AlumnoConsultaXxxDTO getAlumno(@PathVariable int id) {
        AlumnoConsultaXxxDTO alumnoDto = new AlumnoConsultaXxxDTO();
        Alumno alumno = findAlumnoById(id);
        ...
        alumnoDto.curso = alumno.getCurso().getId();
        ...
    }

    private Alumno findBookById(int id) {
        // Consulta a la capa de persistencia
    }
}
```

*Nota: El código no está completo es para dar una idea de como funciona.*

**Edición I**

> muchas gracias por tu respuesta, conozco los DTO pero no es lo que que
>   quiero, quiero poner una anotación en la propiedad curso de la clase
>   alumno, en la clase curso no hay que poner nada, así que cuando quiera
>   recuperar un curso entero podre hacerlo sin problemas.

Después de leer tu comentario busqué un poco y encontré esta froma de hacerlo.
Abajo está la página donde lo encontré, pero puse aquí el código más relevante.

Aclaración: Esta basado en Jackson

```
public class AlumnoSerializer extends StdSerializer<Alumno> {

    public AlumnoSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public AlumnoSerializer(Class<Alumno> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
      Alumno value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);
        ...
        jgen.writeXxxxxxField("itemName", value.itemName);
        ...
        jgen.writeNumberField("curso", value.curso.id);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = AlumnoSerializer.class)
public class Alumno extends Persona{
    ...
}
```

[Adaptado de este link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, conozco los DTO pero no es lo que que quiero, quiero poner una anotación en la propiedad curso de la clase alumno, en la clase curso no hay que poner nada, así que cuando quiera recuperar un curso entero podre hacerlo sin problemas.

Comment: Agregué una solución que puede servirte. Fijate, en la respuesta incluí la página de donde lo saqué.

Comment: muchas gracias, parece interesante

Comment: pero no me termina de convencer, porque ya tienes que hacer una clase, sobreescribir el serializable para que lo serialice a tu manera,.....    tiene que haber algo mas sencillo.

Comment: ademas lo he probado y no funciona, el json de alumno queda en blanco y da error